# Install package version via Metadata API in Apex class

Tags: apex, metadata-api, package-install, mdapi

I am doing automation on package installation after refreshing sandbox
Found and follow this one https://github.com/litify/apex-mdapi/blob/55d755fc0c7e8d519dc10a5a3fa21aa0d7bda17b/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L616

```
findAndInstallLatestPackage() {
    if (packageVersionNumber != null) {
            // Install the package in the current org using the latest version number

            MetadataService.InstalledPackage installedPackage = new MetadataService.InstalledPackage();
            installedPackage.versionNumber = packageVersionNumber;
            installedPackage.password = '....'; //
            installedPackage.fullName = 'MANAERP'; // namespace

            List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results =
                service.upsertMetadata(
                    new MetadataService.Metadata[] { installedPackage });

            handleUpsertResults(results[0]);

        } else {
            System.debug('No package versions found or unable to determine the latest version.');
        }
}
```

for doing test I hardcode `packageVersionNumber` to specific number
Then I tried to open Developer Console and run

```
PackageInstaller a = new PackageInstaller();
a.findAndInstallLatestPackage();
```

But I got error

```
PackageInstaller.MetadataServiceExamplesException: Error occured processing component MANAERP. InstalledPackage namespace: manaerp does not exist! (PACKAGING_API_INSTALL_FAILED).
```

[image]

Im just wondering if can the root cause is the difference between PBO and developer org, The package version was created on PBO org. in that time, we're trying to install in another org?

Comment: Is this a 1GP or a 2GP?

Comment: ah yeah, it's 2GP, then this https://github.com/litify/apex-mdapi/blob/55d755fc0c7e8d519dc10a5a3fa21aa0d7bda17b/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L616 only work for 1GP. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Metadata API’s `InstalledPackage` entity can only be used to install 1GPs. To install a 2GP programmatically, use the Tooling API’s `PacageInstallRequest`.